# Is there a way to apply scipy.stats.normaltest to entire dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I'd like to test my dataframe to see if the data is normally distributed. I found scipy.stats.normaltest, but the examples use arrays to determine if data is normally distributed.

If it's not possible, what's the next based way to determine if the data in a dataframe is normally distributed?

Comment: You can test `df.values.ravel()`, that should work.